# T-SQL: CASE dentro de WHERE

Tags: tsql

Tengo el siguiente `WHERE` donde tengo que poner una claúsula `CASE` para que me haga una búsqueda dependiento del nombre del día y me da un error en el `=`  que está dentro del `THEN`:

```
Declare @dia date = DATENAME(dw,GETDATE())--aqui obtengo el nombre del dia
        Select @Var = COUNT (tc.fecha)
                    FROM tcambio tc
                    INNER JOIN tmoneda tm 
                    ON tc.cod_moneda = tm.cod_moneda
                    WHERE @dia = CASE   WHEN @dia = 'Viernes' THEN tc.Fecha = convert(datetime,(GETDATE()+3))
```

Comment: Esto debería lanzar error en la primera línea: `Declare @dia date = DATENAME(dw,GETDATE())`. Declaras una variable como tipo fecha y quieres guardar el nombre de un día, no hace sentido

Comment: Tienes varios problemas en tu consulta.
 1.- Error de tipo: la variable `@dia` debe ser varchar, no date, debido a que DATENAME retorna un string.
2.- Error de sintaxis: 
    `WHEN @dia = 'Viernes' THEN tc.Fecha = convert(datetime,(GETDATE()+3)) `
Estás haciendo mal la consulta. Después del THEN debe venir el valor con que el que vas a comprar la variable `@dia`. Es decir:
    `WHEN @dia = 'Viernes' THEN convert(datetime,(GETDATE()+3))`
3.- Error de tipo de dato:
Variable `@dia` es tipo varchar y tc.Fecha es tipo date.

Es difícil saber a ciencia cierta lo que quieres.

Comment: Y que deberia hacer el where para los demás dias ?

Comment: ya lo he solucionado con la ayuda de LAMARK:
y quedo asi:
`Select @Var = COUNT (tc.fecha)
     FROM dbo.tcambio tc
     INNER JOIN .dbo.tmoneda tm 
     ON tc.cod_moneda = tm.cod_moneda
     WHERE tc.Fecha = CASE WHEN @dia = 'Viernes' or @dia = 'Friday' THEN  convert(smalldatetime, GETDATE()+3) 
           WHEN @dia = 'Sábado' or @dia = 'Saturday' THEN  convert(smalldatetime, GETDATE()+2)
           WHEN @dia = 'Domingo' or @dia = 'Sunday' or @dia = 'Feriado' or @dia = 'Holiday' 
             THEN convert(smalldatetime, GETDATE()+1)`
            

Muchas gracias por las respuestas.

Comment: @lanshare, por favor [colócalo como una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) y marca la respuesta como ["respuesta aceptada"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) - los comentarios son temporales.

Comment: hola. no se como hacer lo que me pedis.
No veo ningun btn que me permita marcar la respuesta. como hago?

Comment: listo. Lo acabo de hacer. muchas gracias.
Es la primera vez que interactuo en SO.

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucioné con la ayuda de @Lamak y quedo así:

```
Select @Var = COUNT (tc.fecha)
FROM dbo.tcambio tc 
INNER JOIN dbo.tmoneda tm 
    ON tc.cod_moneda = tm.cod_moneda 
WHERE tc.Fecha = CASE
        WHEN @dia = 'Viernes' or @dia = 'Friday' THEN 
            CONVERT(smalldatetime, GETDATE()+3) 
        WHEN @dia = 'Sábado' or @dia = 'Saturday' THEN 
            CONVERT(smalldatetime, GETDATE()+2) 
        WHEN @dia = 'Domingo' or @dia = 'Sunday' or @dia = 'Feriado' or @dia = 'Holiday' THEN 
            CONVERT(smalldatetime, GETDATE()+1)
        END
```