# Modificar dos variables dentro de un THEN

Tags: sql

Buenas Tardes: 
Lo que necesito es lo siguiente:
Dentro de un `CASE` poder manipular dos variables distintas en el `THEN`(ej: `@var1=a` y `@var2=1`) en el caso de que el `WHEN` se cumpla.

No he podido hacerlo. Probé todas las sintaxis posibles pero siempre me da error.
Solo me deja manipular una sola variable en el `THEN` pues al poner `and` o `,` para manipular otra variable me da el error, como trato de representar en negrita en el siguiente ejemplo.

WHEN @dia = 'Viernes' THE GETDATE()+3) ***AND @var=4***

PD: no es una pregunta duplicada.
saludos.
Juan

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu manejador de base de datos? ¿Puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/92394/edit) tu pregunta añadiendo más detalles para saber exactamante qué es lo que necesitas?

Comment: Lo tendrías que hacer en dos columnas por separad, una para cada variable

Comment: ¿Podrías ampliar el contexto? A lo mejor se podría solucionar con un IF

Comment: Posible duplicado de [T-SQL: CASE dentro de WHERE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92291/t-sql-case-dentro-de-where)

Comment: @AlejandroMedina Los duplicados solo se mandan cuando hay una respuesta a la pregunta, que en este caso no tiene

Comment: @Fixtr estoy utilizando MSSQL 10.50 SP1

Comment: @Pedro Quiñonez no estoy manipulando columnas, sino dos variables.

Comment: @M. Gress: acabo de editar el post explicando mejor el problema que tengo. Muchas griacas!

Comment: @AlejandroMedina: No es duplicado. No tiene nada que ver una pregunta con la otra. acabo de editar la pregunta para que se entienda mejor cual es el problema. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En lugar del case usa un `if`, de esta manera te permitira realizar varias acciones tras el `begin`.

```
Declare
@dia varchar(255),
@fecha datetime,
@var int
Set @dia='viernes'

print @dia

IF @dia = 'Viernes'
BEGIN
    Set @fecha=GETDATE()
    Set @var=4      
END

print @fecha
print @var
```

Resultado

> viernes
>
> Ago  3 2017  3:05PM
>
> 4